# REGEX in OQL Query

Tags: regex, oql

I wanted to use regexp while querying OQL objects, so my `select` statement would be:

```
SELECT o  FROM testObject o WHERE ((o.name REGEXP '^d') )
```

But here I am getting exception like

> ```
> 2015-07-23 15:53:50,081 ERROR [WorkerThread#2[127.0.0.1:36335]] centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean
> Get object
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: REGEXP near line 1, column 74 [SELECT o  FROM centina.sa.model.topology.NetworkElement o WHERE ((o.name REGEXP '^d') ) ]
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:603)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
>     at org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.createQuery(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:139)
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:1905)
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:1674)
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:1638)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1158.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor379.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.invoke(RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.java:105)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:193)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:250)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:188)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy285.getAllObjects(Unknown Source)
>     at centina.sa.server.topology.session.TopologySessionBean.getNetworkElements(TopologySessionBean.java:1752)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1157.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:138)
>     at centina.sa.server.fault.interceptor.DatabaseChangeInterceptor.log(DatabaseChangeInterceptor.java:106)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor680.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:83)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:70)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:138)
>     at centina.sa.server.security.interceptor.LoggingInterceptor.log(LoggingInterceptor.java:163)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1048.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:83)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorInterceptor.java:70)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor379.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:79)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:67)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.invoke(RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.java:105)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:361)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
>     at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
>     at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967)
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791)
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:586)
>     at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: REGEXP near line 1, column 74 [SELECT o  FROM centina.sa.model.topology.NetworkElement o WHERE ((o.name REGEXP '^d') ) ]
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:55)
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:48)
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:83)
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:285)
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:183)
>     at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:137)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1694)
>     at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:93)
>     ... 134 more
> 2015-07-23 15:53:50,082 ERROR [WorkerThread#2[127.0.0.1:36335]] centina.sa.server.topology.session.TopologySessionBean
> Get network element
>
> centina.sa.model.error.ErrorCodeException: Database read failure: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: REGEXP near line 1, column 74 [SELECT o  FROM centina.sa.model.topology.NetworkElement o WHERE ((o.name REGEXP '^d') ) ]
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:2092)
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:1674)
>     at centina.sa.server.common.object.session.ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.getAllObjects(ReadOnlyObjectSessionBean.java:1638)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1158.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor379.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
>     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1512708358.java)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
>     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)...................
> ```

Is there any way that I could use regex on OQL object?

Comment: Try `WHERE o.name.startsWith('d')`. Or `WHERE o.name.toString().startsWith("d")`. Or `WHERE /^d/(o.name.toString())`.

Comment: will this work for any pattern,like 

WHERE /any pattern inputted by user/(o.name.toString())

because my requirement is, user will input some pattern which should be appended to oql query.

Comment: I guess yes if the regex is compatible with JavaScript. You can check it with `/(?<=\s)\S+/`regex that uses a lookbehind that is not supported by JS. Does the regex version work now?

Comment: Its not working, this is my query SELECT o  FROM NetworkElement o WHERE /^d/(o.name.toString())

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting '=', found 'd' [SELECT o  FROM centina.sa.model.topology.NetworkElement o WHERE o.name /^d/(o.name.toString())  ]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:603)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:96)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java Tools Tutorials - Herong's Tutorial Notes](http://www.herongyang.com/Java-Tools/jstack-jhat-Object-Query-Language-OQL.html):

> OQL is based on JavaScript expression language.

The regex check can be performed in a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT o  FROM testObject o WHERE "/^d/(o.name.toString())"
```

It seems OQL regex syntax is [very poor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSHRK_4.1.0/itnm/ip/wip/ref/reference/nmip_ref_oqluseofregularexpressions.html). So, not all regular expressions will work here.

Comment: Try this: `SELECT o  FROM testObject o WHERE "/^d/(o.name.toString())"`.

Comment: Or you may also try `SELECT o FROM testObject o WHERE o.name.toString() ~ "/^d/"`. IT says *~ Matches regular expressions.*. Maybe you need `WHERE o.name.toString() Like ^d`.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [SELECT o  FROM centina.sa.model.topology.NetworkElement o WHERE "/^d/(o.name.toString())"]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(Abst i am getting this exception when i tried SELECT o FROM testObject o WHERE "/^d/(o.name.toString())"